# unable to get value from string

Tags: java, android

I have the string as below which I get from hashmap but how can I get lat and lng from below :

```
[lat/lng: (70.0187, -141.0205), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163)]
```

The entire code and flow to how I got here:

```
LatLng allLatLng= new LatLng((lat1),(long1));
all.add(allLatLng);

 map.put("latlng" , all.toString());
```

the second treemap:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
            String value1 =  o1.get("amount");
            String value2 =  o2.get("amount");
            return Integer.parseInt(value1)-Integer.parseInt(value2);
        }
    });

    for (Map<String, String> map1 : list) {
        String id = map1.get("id");
        String amount = map1.get("amount");
        System.out.println("amount= "+amount + " , " +"id = "+id);
  String idlatlng = map1.get("latlng");
        }
```

In the above code I am getting the value of latlng.

```
String idlatlng = map1.get("latlng");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("latlng" , all);
```

And then:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, Object> o1, Map<String, Object> o2) {
        String value1 = (String) o1.get("amount");
        String value2 = (String) o2.get("amount");
        return Integer.parseInt(value1)-Integer.parseInt(value2);
    }
});

for (Map<String, Object> map1 : list) {
    String id = (String) map1.get("id");
    String amount = (String) map1.get("amount");
    System.out.println("amount= "+amount + " , " +"id = "+id);
    List<LatLng> idlatlng = (List<LatLng>) map1.get("latlng");
}
```

Comment: Hello angel_navarro I am getting error at compare return type  :   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "147.212"

Comment: Try using: `return Double.parseDouble(value1).compareTo(Double.parseDouble(value2));`

Comment: it says:: The return type is incompatible with Comparator<Map<String,Object>>.compare(Map<String,Object>, Map<String,Object>

Comment: Or using: `return Double.valueOf(value1).compareTo(Double.valueOf(value2));`

Comment: it says:: cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double

Comment: @jason, please try with the second form (valueOf). This is because parseDouble return `double`, while valueOf return `Double`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38925/discussion-between-jason-and-angel-navarro)

Comment: Its not sorting now .I dont know why ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you are adding all the lat lang values to a single key,you might want to change the way u add values to the hashmap..

i just giving a simple example

```
 LatLng LatLng1= new LatLng((lat1),(long1));
 l1.add(LatLng2);

 map.put("latlng1" , l1.toString());

 LatLng LatLng2= new LatLng((lat2),(long2));
 l2.add(LatLng2);

 map.put("latlng2" , l2.toString());
 // then map.get("latlang1") will give you  lat/lng: (70.0187, -141.0205) 
 String result = map.get("latlang1")//so result will have lat/lng: (70.0187, -141.0205)
 String latlang[]=result.split(":");//will split by the :
 //so latlang[1] will be (70.0187, -141.0205)
 latlang[1].replaceAll("(", "");
 latlang[1].replaceAll("", ")");
 //above lines remove brackets
 //finally split again by "," to get you lat and long
```

Comment: Hello Kaushik. How can I do that ?

Comment: Thanks kaushik but if I have the entire string line like the one right above in the question .How can I deal with that.As I have many lat/lng not 2 but in 1000's.Can youlet me know a workaround for the problem above.Thanks again.

Comment: @jason ok,i think your problem is with parsing assuming that String is that long and still u need the same functionality,i would use help of regex to do that,im not so good in regex, but repost your question as you stated and tag it with regex,to get better help,but as i said i feel it would be better if u store it seperately instead of a single line

Comment: just one more thing if u can change the lat-long values to be seperated by ";" instead of "," it would be fairly trivial

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are putting two Strings in the map. What you need to do is to put the LatLng in the map, as something like this:

```
Map<String, LatLng>;
```

And then get the values of the latitude and the longitude from the LatLng class.